# How to set one variable for each link on a views un-formatted list

Tags: 7, views, navigation, theming

I'm trying to create a variable to put in a l() function. It's the $rellink below.

```
<?php print l('<span class="link-spanner"></span>', "$rellink", array ('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

I have a list of content nodes I'm displaying in an un-formatted view. I want $rellink to be the link for each of them. So on item 1, it's the link to item 1. On item 2 it's the link to item 2 and so forth.

In the unformatted.tpl.php file I can print out

```
<?php print $view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[view_node]']; ?>
```

Which will print the correct link. But I need this inside the link part of the l() function and when I copy and past it in, it doesn't work.

So the question is, what have I done wrong there or if that's not possible/bad practice how do I set-up a variable in my preprocess function that I can use instead?

I've tried this in the preprocess funtion:

```
$view = $variables['view'];
$rellink = $view->style_plugin->row_tokens['$id']['[view_node]'];
```

But it doesn't recognise the global $id variable and I get an un-defined variable rellink variable warning anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally left the quotes in when entering the variable path so it didn't work. I was entering:

```
<?php print l('<span class="link-spanner"> a</span>', "$view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[path]']", array ('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

And the I should've been putting in:

```
<?php print l('<span class="link-spanner"> a</span>', $view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[path]'], array ('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

When you're calling a value in an array, it won't work if you put the path in quotes.